# ¿Cómo crear while obteniendo datos de un select option?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario para registrar mantenimientos, entonces tengo un campo donde pido la frecuencia que seria: Diario, semanal, quincenal, mensual, bimestral, etc. Si selecciono **MENSUAL** debe de insertarme 12 veces el mismo registro equivalentes a 1 Ano, claro, al insertarse debe de cambiar la fecha.

Tengo este código que seria si selecciono la Opción **SEMESTRAL**, si me funciona insertando 2 veces pero la opción cual sea que seleccione se incrementa 2 veces.

¿Logré explicarme?

```php
<?php
    //incluye la clase Libro y Crudmtto
    require_once('crud_mtto.php');
    require_once('mtto.php');
    $crud= new CrudMtto();
    $mtto= new Mtto();

    $s=$_POST["semestral"]; //semestral es el nombre del option SEMESTRAL
        while ( $s<=1) 
        {
            $mtto->setProgramacion($_POST['programacion']);
            $mtto->setEquipo($_POST['equipo']);
            $mtto->setFecha($_POST['fecha']);
            $mtto->setFrecuencia($_POST['frecuencia']);
            $mtto->setTipoMtto($_POST['tipo']);
            $crud->insertar($mtto); 
            header('Location: reg_mtto.php');   
            $s++;   
        }
    // si el elemento insertar no viene nulo llama al crud e inserta un mtto
    if (isset($_POST['insertar'])) 
    {       
    // si el elemento de la vista con nombre actualizar no viene nulo, llama al crud y actualiza el mtto
    }
```

----------CODIGO DEL SELECT-------------------------------------

**

```
<td>Frecuencia:</td>
            <td><select name='frecuencia' >
                <option ></option> 
                <option name="diario" >Diario</option> 
                <option name="semanal" >Semanal</option>
                <option name="quincenal" >Quincenal</option> 
                <option name="mensual" >Mensual</option> 
                <option name="bimestral" >Bimestral</option>
                <option name="trimestral" >Trimestral</option>
                <option name="semestral" >Semestral</option> 
                <option name="anual" >Anual</option> 
                </select></td>
```

--------------------FECHA---------------------------

```
        <td>Fecha de Inicio:</td>
        <td><input type='date' name='fecha' ></td>
```

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes. Sin mayúsculas sostenidas, por favor. No necesitas gritar. Por favor, edita tu pregunta.

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende. Pulsa en [edit] y explícate mejor. Gracias.

Comment: Cual es el código del select option?

Comment: Ya mostre el codigo del select

Answer (score 0):

Del formulario no se mandan los `<option>` sino el `<select>` con el valor de la opción seleccionada,
por lo tanto  `$_POST["semestral"]` no existe, que al compararse con un entero se evalúa como cero.
Entonces obtienes dos iteraciones una para `$s = 0` y otra con el incremento `$s++`.

Puedes manejar el número de frecuencia como valor de la opción:

```
    <option value="0"></option> 
    <option value="365">Diario</option> 
    <option value="?" >Semanal</option>
    <option value="24">Quincenal</option> 
    <option value="12">Mensual</option> 
    <option value="6">Bimestral</option>
    <option value="3">Trimestral</option>
    <option value="2">Semestral</option> 
    <option value="1">Anual</option>
```

Y en lugar de hacer `while` usa `for`:

```
    for( $s=1; $s<=$_POST['frecuencia'], $s++ )
```

El valor de frecuencia semanal depende de tu criterio, incluso puede dar para un código mas complejo.

Comment: Gracias amigo me pudo funcionar. Solo una cosa mas, como puedo hacerle para que si selecciono por ejemplo la frecuencia MENSUAL se me incremente la fecha cada mes, porque en todos los registros me inserta la misma fecha.

Comment: Hay varias maneras, con: `strtotime()`, `mktime()`, `DateTime::add()`, etc.; depende en parte, del origen y tipo de dato de la fecha.

Comment: Me podrias apoyar con un ejemplo? El tipo de dato es Date.

Comment: @Jesus : En PHP no hay tipo Date tal cual, para fechas hay timestamp y DateTime.